# Fade to Transparent in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I've been using the gradient tool to horizontally fade some images to transparent in Gimp v2.8.14.

I just select the layer that I want to fade (usually it's the only layer in the image), select the gradient tool with mode:normal, opacity:100, gradient:FG to Transparent,  shape:linear, repeat:none and drag a line from one end of the image to another.

It's been working fine, and now suddenly it's stopped working. When I drag the line across the image now, it always fades to the foreground color instead of transparency. If I hide the layer from the layers panel, the image disappears and shows the checkered transparency panel underneath, so there's definitely no foreground layer hiding under it.

Comment: Have you tried going to  to layers -> add alpha channel?

Comment: I think you might get a better response on [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like I had to add a layer mask to the image that I want to fade (I wasn't doing that before though). Anyway, if you right-click the layer in the layers panel, select `Add Layer Mask` and choose `White (full opacity)` or whatever that option is called. Then use the gradient to fade the image.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly old post but very helpful to me. I added the "Add Layer Mask" > "Transfer Layers Alpha Channel". This worked with fading to transparent to bg or fg color. Then I added an Alpha Channel to the entire image and was able to fade the layer to tranparent.